# Printing HTML from windows service

Tags: html, windows, service, printing

As the title suggests I need to be able to print HTML documents from inside a windows Service to a USB attached printer. I found this code

public void Print()
        {

```
        Process printjob = new Process();

        string FileName = @"C:\\test.html";

        printjob.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
        printjob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
        printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        printjob.Start();

    }
```

Which some people have suggested works OK.

The initial problem was the USB printer - this code (so I am lead to believe) emulates what 'print file.txt' would do at a command prompt. So having fixed the issue whit that by sharing the printer and then assigning the share through NET USE to lpt1, I can now print .txt files with the above code.

However, printing HTML files only results in a blank page being printed.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can do this without 3rd party software (please). This is currently using .NET v 4.6.1.

Any help would be appreciated as I have spent far too long trying to find a solution to this issue.